# Simple JDBC SQL statement

Tags: java, sql, database

I am trying to type in select parent from parent_list where number = "good" and change = "bad"

Is this correct below? I feel like the word "and" is out of order in the middle.

```
    "SELECT parent FROM parent_list where number="+"'"+good+"'" and change= "+"'"+bad+"'";
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend that you not do it this way.  Use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
static String sql = "SELECT parent FROM parent_list where number= ? and change = ?";


PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1, good);
ps.setString(2, bad);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Binding variables will leave you less vulnerable to SQL injection.  The code is far more readable as well.  `PreparedStatement` escapes `Strings` and `Dates` for you so you don't have to worry about bad quote placement.

You also should make sure that you close your `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` properly - in a finally block, each with its own try/catch wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

### General Case (Basic String Formatting)

Generally speaking, you can use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) to make your life easier when you need to insert arguments into Strings.

```
String.format("number='%s' and change='%'", good, bad);
```

However, this is **not** a good way to do it when you're constructing database queries, for a number of reasons. A special object called `PreparedStatement` exists precisely for that purpose; see below.

### Your Particular Case (Building SQL Queries)

Since you're doing SQL, it's **much better** to use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). This leaves you less vulnerable to injection and also handwaves away some things that can otherwise cause a headache (quotes, dates, etc).

```
String sqlFmt = "SELECT parent FROM parent_list WHERE number= ? AND change = ?";
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlFmt);
statement.setString(1, good);
statement.setString(2, bad);
```

Comment: Wrong, the PreparedStatement is correct for the general case, too.  This is simply bad advice.

Comment: @duffymo How is this bad advice? The general case here is "I want to put variables into a String". A `PreparedStatement` is *not* the correct solution unless the String is a SQL query.

Comment: IMO I would drop the *general case* advice and keep the `PrepatedStatement` usage only. The fact that *works* doesn't mean that *it is how you should do it*.

Comment: Yes, adding values into a String that's not a SQL query would require String.format.  But the wording of your answer suggests that it would be correct in this context.  It's not.  And you only added the PreparedStatement advice after I posted mine.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The reason I started with the general case advice is because the OP is obviously having trouble with basic String formatting. I felt it was better to address the problem that he was actually having, before moving on to telling him a better way to accomplish his task.

Comment: @HenryKeiter still, the first solution won't solve the SQL Injection problem that this query has.

Comment: In any case, the first solution you propose is not the best in terms of security and performance.

Comment: @duffymo (and everyone else) I've added a clarification to the first section that will hopefully ease your concerns a bit.